# How can I download Google Chrome's UI icons?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome have some very beautiful icons in its interface, and I would like to download them.

I would like to use these icons in my next web app. How can I download them, and is it legal to use them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get from Chromium (Chromium is the open source project behind Chrome) source code repository.

- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ui/resources/
- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/releases/1.0.154.53/src/chrome/app/theme/

Chromium is released under the [BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_license)

Comment: +1 BUT... if you are planning on making the app public, make sure the resources are GPL'd as well as the chromium source otherwise you may have the Intellectual property feds on your case...

Comment: Ya some are there but the full list of icons are not there?

Comment: The resource list is split into several pages, use the drop down menu.

Answer (score 3):

There are little tools, which can extract resources from executables and DLLs (). You could try

[Resource Hacker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/Resource-Hacker.shtml)

a free utility to view, modify, add, delete and extract resources in 32bit Windows executables.

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
Application\2.0.172.37\Themes\default.dll
```

Be aware that icons in executables normally are protected by copyright.

---

Google Chrome **Inspector**: You can find Google Chrome Inspector's images on your harddisk (example for Windows Vista):

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
      Application\2.0.172.37\Resources\Inspector\Images
```

---

Comment: Its not retrieving all the icons, can you please tell me how to get all the icons from that DLL