# Where do I find Chrome's default theme file?

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I know how to install themes into Chrome, but I am looking for Chrome's default theme. Specifically the image files to the navigation icons like forward, back, home, reload etc.

I cannot seem to find them. I've googled around for the past 20 minutes and here on the Stack Exchange sites for the past 20 minutes. I simply cannot find them. I even tried unpacking some of the CRX files, but none of them were chrome's default theme.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to restore the default Chrome's theme?

Comment: No, I would like to use the arrows in an application I am creating

Comment: The theme resources are available in the Chromium source near http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ui/resources/

Comment: hey this is looking promising. Is there a way to download this entire folder so I don't have to browse image by image. I am downloading the chromium source tar ball right now. It's 2GB! I am hoping I'll find something in there

Comment: Looks like the tarball I downloaded is the same link you posted. I am extracting that folder to my desktop right now

Comment: Yup they were in there: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ui/resources/default_100_percent/radialmenu_forward.png they were just incomplete. I was thinking they would have all the mouse over states as individual files, but I  guess its up to you to create that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download Google Chrome's UI icons?](http://superuser.com/questions/9939/how-can-i-download-google-chromes-ui-icons)

Answer (score 1):

The default theme as well as the user interface files are not available separately in your Google Chrome installation. As stated by https://superuser.com/users/44887/dan-d , you can access the UI files at http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ui/resources/touch_180_percent/common/

You can also search for PNG files at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search